# Effective Way to Validate Field Values Spark

Tags: python, hadoop, apache-spark, pyspark, bigdata

I need to validate certain columns in a data frame before saving data to hdfs. I want to know if there is an elegant and effective way to do this in pyspark 1.5.2 / python 2.7

For example, say I have the following data

```
+-----+---+
|    a|  b|
+-----+---+
|"foo"|123|
+-----+---+
```

I want to make sure that every value for column `a` is no longer than 3 characters and column `b` is `<= 500`.

My current thought is to write a udf that does a simple if/else, and return a certain value, then based on those results decide whether or not to fail the job. However, for a lot of data, I'm concerned that it will be slow or at least very heavy processing. Is there a well established way of doing this in spark already? Or is there any sort of popular strategy for doing it? I haven't been able to find much information on the subject myself.

I am also open to avoiding spark if there is a better way, any good suggestion would be very helpful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use several predefined [functions](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html?highlight=functions#module-pyspark.sql.functions) to accomplish your objective.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *

df = sc.parallelize([("fo", 100),("alb", 501),("roger", -10),("francis", 1000)]).toDF(["name", "salary"])

df.select("*", ((length("name") < lit(3)) & (col("salary") <= lit(500))).alias("evaluation")).show()

+-------+------+----------+
|   name|salary|evaluation|
+-------+------+----------+
|     fo|   100|      true|
|    alb|   501|     false|
|  roger|   -10|     false|
|francis|  1000|     false|
+-------+------+----------+
```